# How to show that every quadratic, asymptotically nonnegative function $\in \Theta(n^2)$

Tags: complexity-theory, asymptotics

In the book CLRS the authors say that every quadratic, asymptotically nonnegative function $f(n) = an^2 + bn + c$ is an element of $\Theta(n^2)$. Using the following definition

> \begin{align*}
> \Theta(n^2) = \{h(n) \,|\, \exists c_1 > 0, c_2 > 0, n_0 > 0 \,\forall n \geq n_0: 0 \leq c_1n^2 \leq h(n) \leq c_2n^2\}
> \end{align*}

the authors write that $n_0 = 2*\max(|b|/a, \sqrt{|c|/a})$.

I have difficulties proving that the value of $n_0$ is indeed that value.

We know that $a \ge 0$ because otherwise $f$ would not be asymptotically nonnegative. Calculating the roots of $f$ gives us:

\begin{align*}
n_{1/2} &= \frac{-b \, \pm \, \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac} }{2a} \\ 
        &\leq \frac{|b| + \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac} }{a}
\end{align*}

The case $c \ge 0$ gives us:

\begin{align*}
\frac{|b| + \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac} }{2a} \leq \frac{|b| + \sqrt{b^2}  }{a} = 2\frac{|b|}{a}
\end{align*}

which is two times the first argument of the $\max$ function.

But what about the case $c < 0$? How can we find an upper bound for that? Where does the value $\sqrt{|c|/a}$ actually come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CLRS is wrong. For example, the function $0n^2+0n+0$ is asymptotically nonnegative but doesn't belong to $\Theta(n^2)$. Changing "nonnegative" to "positive" doesn't help: you can consider $0n^2+0n+1$. Even requiring the function to be nonconstant doesn't help: consider $0n^2+1n+0$.

Here is a statement which is correct: if $a > 0$ then $an^2+bn+c = \Theta(n^2)$. Indeed, when $n \geq 2\frac{|b|+|c|}{a}+1$ then
$$ |(an^2 + bn + c) - an^2| = |bn+c| \leq |b|n+|c| \leq (|b|+|c|)n < \tfrac{1}{2} an^2, $$
and so
$$ \tfrac{1}{2} an^2 \leq an^2 + bn + c \leq \tfrac{3}{2} an^2. $$

Comment: Thank you, by this doesn't really answer the questions I asked. Also, a quadratic function has by definition $a \ne 0$.

Comment: It answers the question you should have asked, which is: why are eventually positive quadratics in $\Theta(n^2)$. I suggest focusing on that rather than on immaterial details such as what is the minimal (or rather, infimal) $n_0$ which works for the definition.

Comment: Can you recommend a way of finding such a minimal solution? I really want to understand how the authors came up with that value for $n_0$.

Comment: There is no minimal $n_0$. If the quadratic has a root, then any $n_0$ which is strictly larger than the largest root would work (so any $n_0 > \frac{-b+\sqrt{b^2-4ac}}{2a}$). If the quadratic has no roots, then any $n_0$ would work.

Answer (score 2):

So I actually found the answers I was looking for. The case $c \ge 0$ is already handled in the question above. For the case $c < 0$ we have:

\begin{align}
n_{1/2} 
&=   \frac{-b \pm \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{2a} \\
&\le \frac{|b| + \sqrt{b^2 - 4ac}}{a}   \\
&\le \frac{|b| + \sqrt{b^2} + \sqrt{-4ac}}{a} \\
&=   \frac{2|b| + \sqrt{4a|c|}}{a}  \\
&=   \frac{2|b| + 2\sqrt{\frac{a^2|c|}{a}}}{a} \\
&=   2\frac{|b|}{a} +  2\sqrt{\frac{|c|}{a}} \\
&\le 2\max(\{|b|/a, \sqrt{|c|/a}\}) \\
&= n_0
\end{align}

This value for $n_0$ includes the case $c \ge 0$. If $f$ doesn't have any roots, we can instead choose $n_0 = 1$.

For the constants $c_1, c_2$ the authors gave us the values $c_1 = a/4$ and $c_2 = 7a/4$. To check that these are correct we do the following:

Since $n \ge 2|b|/a$ and $n \ge 2\sqrt{|c|/a}$, we know that:
\begin{alignat}{3}
&& \frac{1}{2} &\ge  &\frac{|b|}{an} \quad&\text{and}\quad &\frac{1}{4} \ge  &\frac{|c|}{an^2} \\
&&-\frac{1}{2} &\le -&\frac{|b|}{an} \quad&\text{and}\quad -&\frac{1}{4} \le -&\frac{|c|}{an^2}
\end{alignat}

This gives us

\begin{alignat}{2}
&\frac{1}{4} =   1 - \frac{1}{2} - \frac{1}{4} \le 1 - \frac{|b|}{an} - \frac{|c|}{an^2} \le 1 + \frac{b}{an} + \frac{c}{an^2} \\
\text{and therefore}\quad
&\frac{a}{4}n^2 \le an^2 + bn + c
\end{alignat}

and

\begin{alignat}{2}
&1 + \frac{b}{an} + \frac{c}{an^2} \le 
 1 + \frac{|b|}{an} + \frac{|c|}{an^2} \le
 1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{4} =
 \frac{7}{4} \\ 
\text{and therefore}\quad
&an^2 + bn + c \le \frac{7a}{4}n^2
\end{alignat}

which shows that the values $c_1 = a/4$ and $c_2 = 7a/4$ are indeed correct.